Ruby on Rails: Railway deployment - URL says something is wrong. Logs don't show anything
So I deployed my rails app to Railway. The url being deployed to shows this:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

The logs just show this:
Rack::Handler is deprecated and replaced by Rackup::Handler
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.4 application starting in production
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 6.0.2 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("Sunflower")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: production
*          PID: 7
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7256
Use Ctrl-C to stop

Is it really possible that the reason the app isn't running correctly is because of the rackup issue?
These are the variables I have set:

Here is my production.rb:
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.active_storage.service = :local
  config.log_level = :info
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: "apikey",
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
    domain: "XXXXXXX-production.up.railway.app",
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'XXXXXXX-production.up.railway.app', protocol: 'https' }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.hosts << "XXXXXXX-production.up.railway.app"
end


This error is app level, it is an error from your rails app not the service you host it on. Puma has obviously booted without any problem. It is then a bit weird Puma is not returning logs about the error...

Does it run locally in the development environment?
